# Why applicationDidFinishLaunching is called after viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my **mac** app (swift) the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in appDelegate is called *after* the `viewDidLoad` method of my view controller. The view controller is invoked by the window controller which is the entry point of the app. Anyone can help me? Thanks

My code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` simply checks if a folder exists:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    print("method called")

    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("folder")

    if !NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath) {
        do {
            try Global.fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            print("success")

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: @vadian why do you think this is a duplicate? I'm speaking about a MAC app, which is completely different from the other question

Comment: Ernesto, why are you surprised? You most likely instantiate your view and window controllers from storyboard (i.e. NSMainStoryboardFile in your plist it set to something) that's why the viewDidLoad is called before. 1) If you need it to call after or in-time just switch to manual creation of your View and Window 2) Why do you need this?

Comment: Also keep in mind that invocation of viewDidLoad only means that its view controller was **loaded to memory** it doesn't mean that it is already starting to appear (that's what makes it specific compared to viewWillAppear which is triggered exactly when the view is about to appear).

Comment: Thanks you for your help! Usually I develop iOS apps and I use storyboard but the appDelegate method is called before everything! Can you suggest me how to create manually my window from AppDelegate? I instantiated the view controller but I can't figure out how to show it, I think something about presentViewController but I'm not able to do it.. Anyway I need it because I need to check if user has already logged in, otherwise I must show the login page. Thanks you so much

Comment: In iOS this can be different - I understand your confusion but default Cocoa template with storyboard works exactly this way: viewDidLoad then appDidFinish...

See [this](https://github.com/stanislaw/UISpec.app/blob/58cd5f1ac612dbe504477d39ea103c9dfaba49a8/UISpec/UISpec/Classes/Use%20Cases/Stage/StageUseCase.swift#L19) - this app doesn't use storyboards/xibs - let me know if that is enough for you to get started -

Comment: That app is a bit custom: you can just add all window/windowController related code from there to your appDidFinishLaunching code and make sure to retain them all (i.e. store them as strong vars).

Comment: Thanks you very much I will try reading that code! Thanks ;)